# Stop a parameterized test suite in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, junit4

Given a certain set of parameters is it possible to stop a set of tests against a single parameter.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Test{
    public Test(String a, String b){
        if(!a.equals(b)){
            // Stop do not run tests
        } // else go on run tests
    }
}
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> getParams(){
    return  Array.asList(new Object[][]{ {"aa","aa"},{"aa","bb"} };
}
@Test
public void test1(){ assertTrue(false); }
```

Did not test the code above just to give an idea what I am trying to accomplish. The constructor is actually trying to gain resources and if a resource fails to be acquired I do not want the tests to be attempted.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move your logic into `getParams()` method, so if you can't "gain resources" there, you can simply return an empty collection of parameters, so nothing to run.

Comment: This might be acceptable but would make it harder for extended classes to over ride the getParams() method.

Comment: You can always move this logic into an external helper class, but this is outside of your original question.

Comment: I understand I could minimize the effort in over riding getParams() methods by providing helper methods in the parent Parent.setUpBlah() but I do not want to expose those methods to the extended class; But my initial question was to see if there is a way to stop or cancel a set of tests for a given parameter. I do appreciate your input though.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try it but doing an assert in the constructor will fail all the tests if it fails. But have some points :)